# Jenkins variable in catchError block - No such property

Tags: jenkins

`buildResults` variable isn't accessible from outside of `catchError` block. Any idea how I can access it? `build job` might get aborted so I want the rest of the script block to continue but I get the error `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: buildResults for class: groovy.lang.Binding`

```
                        catchError {
                            buildResults = build job: 'Test', parameters: [string(name: 'BRANCH', value:'main')], wait: true                
                        }
                        
                        sh """ curl -u 123:123 -X POST \
                            -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
                            --url 'http://10.10.10.10:8080/rest/api/2/issue/${env.TASK_KEY}/comment' \
                            -d '{ "body": "[Test] Full Pipeline result is: ${buildResults.getResult()}"}'
                        """
```

Answer (score 0):

If you downstream job will be aborted, the build function will threw an exception, which means the `buildResults` parameter will not be set and you will get the `MissingPropertyException` error.
To overcome it you can define the `buildResults` parameter with a default value, prior to calling the `build` function, which will make it available regardless of the build function execution:

```groovy
def buildResults = ''
catchError {
    buildResults = build job: 'Test', parameters: [string(name: 'BRANCH', value:'main')], wait: true                
}
```

In addition you will have to update the usage of the build result as it may not contain a result object if the downstream was aborted, and in that case `buildResults.getResult()` will fail.
You can use something like to solve it:

```groovy
def buildResults = ''
catchError {
    buildResults = build job: 'Test', parameters: [string(name: 'BRANCH', value:'main')], wait: true                
}
def results = buildResults ? buildResults.getResult() : "Downstream job did not return results"
sh """curl -u 123:123 -X POST \
      -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
      --url 'http://10.10.10.10:8080/rest/api/2/issue/${env.TASK_KEY}/comment' \
      -d '{ "body": "[Test] Full Pipeline result is: ${results}"}'
"""
```